# Cannot get CSS translateZ to work on Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transforms

I have searched around but all the solutions don't seem to work.

Here is the HTML structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to apply transformations to the `child` elements like so: `translate(39.375%, 10.7843%) translateZ(3px)`

The `x` and `y` translations work fine, but I cannot get `translateZ` to work.

I have also tried applying `perspective:1000` to the parent as well as `-webkit-perspective` with no luck.

This works perfectly on Safari but not on Chrome (even without `perspective`)

Comment: `perspective:1000` --> perspective:1000px with a unit

Comment: @TemaniAfif Nope, still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried with translate3d(x,y,z) instead of translate() and translateZ()?

Comment: @FrancescoOrsi Still no luck unfortunately, only works on Safari for some reason. I'm not sure why, I'm not using CSS frameworks or anything - just the small HTML shown above

Comment: @FrancescoOrsi Z-index does work on the other hand, so I will have to work with that.